# Regarding Apostol's theory of integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, reference-request

I have some questions regarding the theory of integration as discussed in Tom Apostol's *Calculus*. Integration is defined using step functions. My question is, is this definition he presents equivalent to the standard definition of the Riemann integral found in other textbooks? I am asking this because other definitions talk about stuff like "mesh" and "tagged partitions". Moreover, some use epsilons and deltas. He does not use these more advanced concepts, so I am concerned that he may be taking a "Riemann Integral for dummies" approach.

Secondly, on page 76, he says the following:

> "Two fundamental questions arise at this stage: (1) Which bounded functions are integrable?...A complete answer to question (1) lies beyond the scope of an introductory course and will not be given in this book. Instead, we shall give partial answers which require only elementary ideas."

Where can I find a text which discusses this question comprehensively?

Comment: I looked in the book: his definition is completely standard (via upper and lower integral), it is sometimes called the Darboux integral, but it's equivalent to the one given by tagged partitions and mesh going to zero. This equivalence is in any basic analysis book. Riemann integrable (=Darboux integrable) functions are bounded functions continuous except on a set of measure zero. As completely random choice of a text, see Strichartz: The way of analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree entirely with user8268's comment. You don't need to worry about this being an approach to integration "for dummies." Apostol's book is completely rigorous, except for a handful of places in the second volume where a difficult proof may be omitted, and even when that happens he is always completely upfront about it.

If you are interested in Lebesgue's criterion for the Riemann-integrability of a bounded function, you can find it for instance in Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis, 2nd Ed.*, Theorem 7.48. In my view, Apostol's decision to exclude this fact from his calculus book is entirely reasonable. At this level, its proof (and even its statement) would be a considerable digression.

The business with "meshes" and "tagged partitions" has to do with Riemann sums, which don't seem to be discussed in Apostol's calculus book. If you'd like to see a proof of the theorem that Riemann sums "converge" to the integral whenever a function is integrable, see Spivak's *Calculus, 3rd ed.*, Chapter 13, Appendix. (I write "converge" in quotation marks because it is not exactly convergence in the usual sense.) Also see Chapter 22, Exercise 9, in Spivak for some practical applications of this fact. You'll probably want to postpone this last part until you've studied convergence of sequences.